# How to bind to a private list in a window?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I have a window with a `private List<Tuple<string, string, char>> _trasitions`.
In the same window there is a `DataGrid` called `dataTrans`. How to bind (preferably in XAML) `_transitions` to `dataTrans.ItemsSource`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see sample code here : You would have to.

1. Move the list to a viewmodel class.

2. Expose a public property for that list.

3. Set the data context of the window to an instance of the viewmodel class.

4. Bind the Property to the ItemSource of the datagrid in XAML.

Sample code given below

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestWPFApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWPFApp"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Transitions}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="firstColumn" Header="First" Binding="{Binding Path=Item1, Mode= OneWay}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="secondColumn" Header="Second" Binding="{Binding Path=Item2, Mode= OneWay}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="thirdColumn" Header="Third" Binding="{Binding Path=Item3, Mode= OneWay}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System;
namespace TestWPFApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
        }
    }

    public class MainViewModel
    {
        private List<Tuple<string, string, char>> _transitions = new List<Tuple<string, string, char>>();

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Transitions.Add(new Tuple<string,string,char>("First Item 1","Second Item 1",'A'));
            Transitions.Add(new Tuple<string, string, char>("First Item 2", "Second Item 2", 'B'));
            Transitions.Add(new Tuple<string, string, char>("First Item 3", "Second Item 3", 'C'));
            Transitions.Add(new Tuple<string, string, char>("First Item 4", "Second Item 4", 'D'));
        }
        public List<Tuple<string, string, char>> Transitions
        {
            get { return _transitions; }
            set
            {
                _transitions = value;
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to expose the collection as a public property to bind to it.

```
public List<Tuple<string, string, char>> Transitions
{
    get { return this.transitions };
}
```

I would also recommend defining a type rather than using a `Tuple`, and if you want the UI to be notified of collection changes, then you should make the collection an `ObservableCollection` rather than a `List`.

If the collection reference changes, you'll also need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and invoke the `PropertyChanged` event when the reference changes (e.g. in a setter).

To bind a `DataGrid`, set its `ItemsSource` property:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Transitions}" ... />
```

You must ensure that the data context for the `DataGrid` is an instance of your view model. See http://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html for more info.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. Two reasons

- You can only bind properties.
- The property must be public.

For more information please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#basic_data_binding_concepts)

So the only option I see is to wrap your field in a property as **devdigital** already posted.